# How can I use types declared in a namespace inside a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, directx-11

I'm making a DirectX11 App in Visual Studio 2017 using C++, I need to declare a data structure in my "GeometryGenerator.h" header file.

The problem is that when I try to use the types: XMFLOAT3 in my header file I got an error from Visual Studio when I try to run the project and gives me this message:

```
“C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed”
```

In the lines where I declare variables of type XMFLOAT3

This is my code:

```
#pragma once
#include "..\Common\DeviceResources.h"
#include "ShaderStructures.h"
#include "..\Common\StepTimer.h"

namespace DirectX11Engine
{

    class GeometryGenerator {
    public: 
        struct Vertex
        {
            Vertex() {}
            Vertex(const XMFLOAT3& p, const XMFLOAT3& n, const XMFLOAT3& t, const XMFLOAT2& uv)
                : Position(p), Normal(n), TangentU(t), TexC(uv) {}
            Vertex(
                float px, float py, float pz,
                float nx, float ny, float nz,
                float tx, float ty, float tz,
                float u, float v)
                : Position(px, py, pz), Normal(nx, ny, nz),
                TangentU(tx, ty, tz), TexC(u, v) {}

            XMFLOAT3 Position;
            XMFLOAT3 Normal;
            XMFLOAT3 TangentU;
            XMFLOAT2 TexC;
        };
        void PruebaDeTipos();

    };

}
```

If I add this:

```
using namespace DirectX;
```

I get rid of the problem. My question is whether `using namespaces X` in header files a bad and dangerous practice in C++? And also how then can I use types declared in their own namespaces inside .cpp files?

Comment: Use `DirectX::XMFLOAT3` instead of `XMFLOAT3`

Comment: Using namespaces foo is bad to do in header files, especially if you have multiple namespaces, as this would defeat the purpose of namespaces. DirectX::XMFLOAT3 is a correct way

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace for reference

Comment: It's best to always copy the exact error message (instead of paraphrasing) from the Output Tab (yes the output tab not the errors list).

Comment: "How can I use types declared in namespaces inside .cpp files?" - you simply use their full name. For example `DirectX::XMFLOAT3`.

Comment: You should use full name resolution in the header (``DirectX::XMFLOAT3``), and then in your source file (after all your ``#include`` statements), put a ``using namespace DirectX;``. In fact, I noted this when I wrote the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxmath/pg-xnamath-migration#namespaces) for [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I use types declared in namespaces inside .cpp files?

You use the [*scope resolution operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator), like this in your case:

```
Vertex(const DirectX::XMFLOAT3& p, const DirectX::XMFLOAT3& n, const DirectX::XMFLOAT3& t, const DirectX::XMFLOAT2& uv)

...

DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Position;
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Normal;
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 TangentU;
DirectX::XMFLOAT2 TexC;
```

and so on for every time you are referring to a name in that namespace.

A second option, in case you really wish to avoid typing the namespace per each usage in the header file is using the following `using` syntax:

```
using XMFLOAT3 = DirectX::XMFLOAT3;
```

By *aliasing* like this, you can use whatever name you put before the `=` instead of the whole `DirectX::XMFLOAT3`. But do take into consideration that if you do so in a relatively global context (such as file or enscoping namespace) then anyone familiar with the namespace, `DirectX` for example, would have to remember your aliases when going over your code, as opposed to the quite recognizable and unambiguous first option of specifying the full name.

> but Is adding namespaces in header files a bad and dangerous practice
>   in C++?

Indeed, see comprehensive explanation here: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).